# what should be entries in extensions /& sip /& queue conf in Asterisk for call forwarding by default?

Tags: asterisk

I am trying to learn how i can add call forwarding facility for few phones by default in Asterisk via conf files entries. My Asterisk version 1.6.2.6

I read http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+call+forwarding

In my scenario i have 3 entries like 10,11,12 which always answer the calls.
But i am trying to do call forwarding ie if 10 busy then call should go to 11, if 11 busy then call goes to 12,if 12 then call end with recorded tape that 'all are busy'.
For that i read above link data, as per my knowledge i have to change my dial plan. but in examples all showing first i should click # key & save it. but i need by default call forwarding. As if phone 50 calls 10 then if 10 not busy then it goes to 10 only. But if 51 calls 10 then it goes to 11 because 10 busy with 50.
I am giving example of phone 10 entries in Asterisk conf files same for other also. 
My extension.conf entries:

```
exten => 0010,2,Queue(0010)
exten => 0110,1,Dial(SIP/0110)
exten => 0210,1,Dial(SIP/0210)
```

My sip.conf entries:

```
[0010]
username = 0010
secret = 0010
type = friend
insecure = port,invite
host = dynamic
context = users
[0110]
username = 0110
secret = 0110
type = friend
insecure = port,invite
host = dynamic
context = users
[0210]
username = 0210
secret = 0210
type = friend
insecure = port,invite
host = dynamic
context = users
```

My queues.conf entries:-

```
[0010]
member => SIP/0010
```

Where & what i should add in above entries so call forwarding done in my Asterisk?

Answer (score 1):

Please check this book

http://www.asteriskdocs.org/en/3rd_Edition/asterisk-book-html/asterisk-book.html#asterisk-ACD

Or this book

http://cdn.oreilly.com/books/9780596510480.pdf

Both have full description for your case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Asterisk 10,centos 6. and I'V done changes in conf file as below for call forwarding

```
"extension.conf"
 exten => 0010,1,Wait(0.05)
 exten => 0010,2,Queue(0010)
 exten => 0010,n,Dial(SIP/0011,15)
 exten => 0010,n,Dial(SIP/0012,15)
 exten => 0110,1,Dial(SIP/0110)
 exten => 0210,1,Dial(SIP/0210)

"queues.conf"
;----------------------QUEUE TIMING OPTIONS------------------------------------
timeout = 15
retry = 5
;timeoutpriority = app|conf
timeoutpriority = conf

[0010]
member => SIP/0010
[0011]
member => SIP/0011
[0012]
member => SIP/0012
```

Please suggest wheather i'm right if not then please suggest some answer based on given .conf files